# Find $y'$ and $y''$ : $ y=x^2\ln(2x)$

Tags: calculus

for $x> 0$ : $ y=x^2\ln(2x)$

Product rule:
$$(x^2)\cdot[\ln (2x)]'+ (\ln (2x))\cdot[x^2]' $$

$$y'= x^2\frac{1}{2x}\cdot (2)+\ln(2x)\cdot(2x) =2x\ln(2x)$$

$$y''=(2x)[\ln(2x)]'+(\ln(2x))[2x]'+[x]'$$

$$=2x\cdot \frac{1}{2x}+\ln(2x)\cdot (2)+1$$

$$=1+\ln(2x)\cdot (2)+1$$

$$=2\ln(2x)+2$$

However, the answer in the book is: $2\ln(2x)+3$

How? What have I done wrong?

Comment: In your derivation of $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(2x)$ in your product rule computation for $y''$ you forgot to multiply by $2$, which is required by the chain rule.

Comment: Also, in $y'$, you forget to add $x$ from the first term.

Comment: so if it was by itself the answer world be $\frac{1}{ln(2x}\cdot (2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y = x^2 \ln 2x$$

Using the product rule we get $$y' = 2x \cdot \ln 2x + {\color{blue}{x^2 \cdot \frac{2}{2x}}}$$ which simplifies to $$y' = 2x \ln 2x + {\color{blue}{x}}$$

Then differentiating this again using the product rule on the first term we get $$y'' = 2 \ln 2x + 2x \cdot \frac{2}{2x}  + x = 2 \ln 2x + 3$$

Remember: $${\color{blue}{x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{x} = x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

So, your function is $y(x)=x^2 \ln(2x).$ Let's check.  $y'(x)=2x \ln(2x)+x^2 \times \frac{2}{2x}=2x \ln(2x)+x.$ Now, $$y"=[2x \ln(2x)+x]'=2\ln(x)+2x \times \frac{2}{2x}+1=2\ln(x)+3.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y\prime(x)=(x^{2}Ln(2x))\prime$$
$$=2x.Ln(2x)+x^{2}.\frac{2}{2x}$$
$$=2xLn(2x)+x$$
$$y\prime\prime(x)=2Ln(2x)+2x.\frac{2}{2x}+1$$
$$=2Ln(2x)+3$$

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be better to simplify the expression before differentiation: 
$$\begin{align}y &= x^2 \, \ln(2x) = x^2 (\ln 2 + \ln x)\\
y' &= x^2\left(\frac 1x\right)+2x(\ln2 + \ln x)\\
&=x(1+2\ln 2 +2\ln x)\\
y''&=\left(1+2\ln 2 + 2 \ln x\right)+x\cdot \frac 2 x\\
&=3+2\ln(2x)\end{align} $$